# Just give me the facts

Tags: word-usage, difference

(**At The Police Station**)

**Cop**: Witness said his name was John.

**Boy**: Witness?

**Cop**: Yes, you're the witness. You witnessed something. You saw something happened, an emergency, an accident. Isn't that right?

**Boy**: Well, yes, but you see I was just over and ...

**Cop**: **Just give me the facts**, sir, please, just the facts. Address?

**Boy**: The facts? The address?

**Cop**: Yes. Where did you witness this accident?

---

What does "Just **give** me the facts" mean?

Does it mean "Just **tell** me the facts"?

Comment: You probably want someone to ***give** you the answer to your question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, *give me* means *provide me with*, so the cop is effectively saying "I don't want any speculations, or excuses, or lies - provide me with factual information".

*Give* can be more general too, if you *give someone trouble* you're not *providing* them with anything, but you are causing them to experience problems. So you can read "*give me the facts*" as the cop saying that they don't want to hear anything that's untrue, they don't want their time to be wasted, etc.

So the witness doesn't necessarily need to say anything, if they have no information to give! But in this situation, they'll probably be forced to answer questions. Also, *just the facts [ma'am/sir]* is a police cliché, a thing that characters often say when they're interviewing witnesses.